# Android facebook SDK, upload pictures to wall with profile in different language?

Tags: android, facebook, upload, image

Currently I'm able to post mesages and pictures to my wall using my app, by looking for the album "Wall Photos" it works fine so far, i let a friend of mine to test my app on his phone to see if it works fine with any user, when he tried to upload a picture it didn't work, now i think it might be have something to do with the fact that his profile is in spanish, so looking for the album "Wall photos" could not be possible, i took a look at his photo albums and for my surprise he didn't have any "Wall photos" album equivalent in his language,
So.. long story short:

a) How can i look for the "Wall Photos" album if the user's profile is in a different language?

b) How can i create a "Wall Photos" album in case that it doesn't exists?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your code how you are uploading image to facebook. And this is one sample code which is working fine for me just have a look might be helpful to you. And in my code am not creating any album Wall Photos. My picture gets uploaded in wall itself. Just have a look ...

```
private void fbImageSubmit() {
    if (facebook != null) {
        if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            try {
                byte[] data = null;

                // Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Constants.imgShare);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmScreen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                data = baos.toByteArray();

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", strmsg);
                parameters.putString("method", "photos.upload");
                parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);

                facebook.request(null, parameters, "POST");
                /*
                 * time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getHours() + ":"
                 * + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes();
                 */

                currentTime = DateFormat.format("hh:mm", d.getTime());
                currentDate = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", d.getTime());

                Cursor cursor = Constants.dbHelper
                        .GetDataFromImageName(Constants.enhancedImage
                                .getImagename());
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    Constants.dbHelper.updateData(currentDate.toString(),
                            currentTime.toString(), "Facebook", "Image");
                } else {
                    Constants.dbHelper.insertData("true");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Image uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// bmscreen is my bitmap of image ;
Hope might be helpful to you.

Comment: I tried the code and it does upload the photo to the wall, but for some reason the "nessage" parameter seems to not being passed, it only shows the picture without the message. Using "caption" instead of "message" seems to work.

Comment: almost, I'm still having issues on how to cancel an Asynchronus task when the user presses the "back" button. I guess I'm gonna have to ask help here if i can't figure it out. :(. Thanks for your answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer so people can look at our comments, and try what method works for them.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
parameters.putString("caption", "ooo xxx");
```

instead of

```
parameters.putString("message", "test post on wall");
```

should do the trick, it works to me :)

ps. thanks to user for sharing his answer, it really helps :D

Answer (score 0):

> a) How can i look for the "Wall Photos" album if the user's profile is in a different language?

Set the `locale` parameter to `en_US` while querying the Graph API for albums – then you’ll get "Wall Photos" and not the localized album name.

> b) How can i create a "Wall Photos" album in case that it doesn't exists?

Uh, I don’t think creating it yourself would be a good idea, since normally it’s automatically created by Facebook – so that might clash when FB later creates an album for the user’s first actual wall posted photo.