# Share text/Image on twitter and facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I have developed my news app and now i have to add share(facebook/twitter)option to share image and text.I have searched lot but not clear how to fulfill my requirement.Actually on share button i have to display edittext and button and whatever we have to share on clicking on share button that should be shared.I have gone through SDK and intent also but not working for my requirement`

```
String twitterUri = "http://m.twitter.com/?status=";
        String marketUri = "TESTING ";
        Intent shareOnTwitterIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(twitterUri + marketUri));
        startActivity(shareOnTwitterIntent);.
```

Comment: Start by reading [this for facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) and [this for twitter](http://blog.tarams.com/?p=212).  But also start with searching.  There are lots of answered questions on SO already about it.

Comment: Thanks @AleksG Really its good guide,But i have to develop app such that it will ask for userId and password and then tweet on the user wall.But this apps tweets on developer wall...

Comment: No, it won't be developer's wall.  I used that for implementing this functionality in my app.

Comment: can you describe it in brief,how have you done.If you talk about this code, i have used this code and this posts on developers wall only....it accepts different username and password but post on developers wall

Comment: reason for downvote please write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can get help from the below link for facebook image uploading

[Android facebook SDK, upload pictures to wall with profile in different language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629613/android-facebook-sdk-upload-pictures-to-wall-with-profile-in-different-language/10630222#10630222)

and for Twitter you need to upload it in twitpic... for that you have to use jar file.. as you can't tweet picture in twitter.

Comment: any link for uploading picture to twitpic @user

Comment: for TwitPic example : http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-send-image-to-twitpic-from-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can share image and test on twitter by using 
    twitter4j-core-3.0.2.jar
    twitter4j-media-support-3.0.2.jar
library. 
example

```
String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
 String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

 AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
 twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
 twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

 ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
 cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(yourConsumerKey).setOAuthConsumerSecret(yourConsumerSeceret).setOAuthAccessToken(yourAccessToken).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(yourAccessTokenSeceret);

 Configuration conf = cb.build();

 ImageUploadFactory factory = new ImageUploadFactory(conf);
 ImageUpload upload = factory.getInstance();
 String url = upload.upload(yourImage, yourCaptionWithImage); //image is a File Format and Caption is String
```

Reference link :

1) http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-send-image-to-twitpic-from-android/

2) http://www.rqna.net/qna/wupzh-android-image-sharing-on-twitter-using-sdk.html