# How to upload Image on facebook wall? Using facebook sdk on android

Tags: android, facebook

How to upload Image on facebook wall? Using facebook sdk on android

here's my code :

public void postToWall() {

```
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }





        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            // ??????????
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: [Try this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629613/android-facebook-sdk-upload-pictures-to-wall-with-profile-in-different-language)

It might work for what you're looking for.

Comment: i already figure out, thanks though